# Multiple Table Access Query

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am trying to combine multiple tables in Microsoft Access to return a LIKE wildcard value. However, I want it done by a list of things, not just a specific item. I have the below table labled "SomeData"

```
ID  Fund    TextFld             Type1
2   Sewer   COMP -              DZ Docs
3   Sewer   SEW:                ZO Docs
```

I have a second table labeled GL where in I am looking up on TextFld: For instance there might be:

```
COMP - ABC
COMP - DEF
SEW: GHS
SEW: XYZ
```

I put into SQL:

```
SELECT GL.Text, SomeData.Type1
FROM SomeData INNER JOIN GL ON SomeData.Fund = GL.Type
WHERE GL.Text LIKE SomeData.TextFld;
```

However, this is only returning exact matches. How can I do this so that any similar match will be found.

Please note that there will be many lines of these, so I cannot just use anything such as LIKE "COMP*" OR "SEW*"

Thank you very much in advance. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have the wildcard in your query.  The wildcard in MS Access is the asterisk so your query should look like this:

```
SELECT GL.Text, SomeData.Type1
FROM SomeData INNER JOIN GL ON SomeData.Fund = GL.Type
WHERE GL.Text LIKE '*' & SomeData.TextFld & '*';
```

I haven't ever used a LIKE statement while using a field from another table but I'm fairly certain that syntax is correct.

**Note:** In this query you are getting any records where the `COMP` or `SEW` exists anywhere in the field.  If you want it to show only when it is found at the start of the field it would be:

```
WHERE GL.Text LIKE & SomeData.TextFld & '*';
```

And likewise if you want it to only match where it is found at the end:

```
WHERE GL.Text LIKE '*' & SomeData.TextFld;
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. Yes, I needed to show it with both single quotes

Answer (score 0):

You should concatenate wild character at the end (or beginning, or both) of the field TextFld

```
WHERE GL.Text LIKE '%' + SomeData.TextFld + '%'
```